# PyQt6 QSlider how to set groove color?

Tags: pyqt6, qslider

I want to set the groove color of a slider. The default is orange, below I try to set it to green but this does nothing .. what am I getting wrong? Maybe my naming is wrong. Can anyone correct the code below to set the lower portion of the slider to green?

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(400)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: yellow")

        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
        styles = "QSlider::sub-page:vertical { background: green; }"
        self.slider.setStyleSheet(styles)
        self.slider.setFixedHeight(300)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.slider)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: 1. Don't try to use the layout of a QMainWindow, use `setCentralWidget()` instead (possibly with a container QWidget with its own layout ); 2. **never** set generic properties for containers (including windows), as they propagate to *all* children; use [selector types](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) instead; 3. as also written in [the docs](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls): "With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well."